# How to use hammer.js plugins with require.js

Tags: requirejs, hammer.js

I am trying to use hammer.js plugins with require.js but I have no luck.

Here is my code:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
      "jquery": ('__proto__' in {}) ? "lib/zepto" : "lib/jquery",
      "hammer-jquery": "lib/jquery.hammer",
      "hammer-showtouches": "lib/hammer.showtouches",
      "hammer-fakemultitouch": "lib/hammer.fakemultitouch"
  },
  shim: {
      "jquery": {
          exports: "$"
      },
      "hammer-showtouches": {
          deps: [ "hammer-jquery" ],
          exports: "Hammer.plugins.showTouches"
      },
      "hammer-fakemultitouch": {
          deps: [ "hammer-jquery" ],
          exports: "Hammer.plugins.fakeMultitouch"
      }
  },
  waitSeconds: 30
});

requirejs(["jquery","hammer-jquery","hammer-showtouches","hammer-fakemultitouch"], function ($,Hammer) {
    $(function(){
      if(!Hammer.HAS_TOUCHEVENTS && !Hammer.HAS_POINTEREVENTS) {
            Hammer.plugins.showTouches();
            Hammer.plugins.fakeMultitouch();
          }
    });
});
```

And here is the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined hammer.showtouches.js:7

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined require.js:8

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined hammer.fakemultitouch.js:7

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined require.js:8

I have tried to include Hammer in shim config with no luck (It's not necessary beacause last version of jquery.hammer is AMD compatible).

Answer (score 2):

**Your issue appears to be that you didn't include the `hammerjs` library which is *required* by the `hammerjs jquery` plugin.**

To fix this problem, you'll need to add to your `requirejs` path something like `'hammer':'lib/hammerjs/dist/hammer.min',`

---

**Additionally, here's some related information on how I used `hammerjs` with `requirejs`.**

In my case, I wanted it to work with `backbone` and `requirejs`. I installed the libraries with `bower`.

```
bower install --save hammerjs
bower install --save backbone.hammer
```

Then, I proceeded to add the RequireJS configuration:

- I noticed that `jquery.hammer.js` is AMD and automatically requires jquery. It also silently depends on Hammer. It modifies jquery to support Hammer. No shim is required.
- I noticed that `hammerjs` is AMD and automatically exports Hammer. No shim is required.
- I noticed that `backbone.hammer` is AMD and automatically requires `underscore`, `backbone`, and `hammer`. It modifies Backbone to support Hammer. No shim is required.

Therefore, my configuration uses paths only (since no shim support is required):

```
require.config({
    'baseUrl':'',
    'paths':{
        'underscore':'js/lib/underscore-amd/underscore-min',
        'backbone':'js/lib/backbone-amd/backbone-min',
        'jquery':'js/lib/jquery/jquery.min',
        'hammer':'js/lib/hammerjs/dist/hammer.min',
        'jquery-hammer':'js/lib/hammerjs/dist/jquery.hammer.min',
        'backbone-hammer':'js/lib/backbone.hammer/backbone.hammer'
    },
    shim:{
        'underscore': { exports: '_' },
        'backbone': { deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'], exports: 'Backbone' }
    }
});
```

Comment: How should I integrate this if I want to have swipeleft and swiperight events on my Backbone View?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap HammerJS then bind to the global window:

```
// @path utils/hammer
define([
  'hammer'
], function (Hammer) {
  window.Hammer = Hammer;
});
```

Then make whatever plugins or modules which have dependencies on HammerJS depend on `utils/hammer`.